# Как задать цвет конкретным ячейкам или строкам TableView в зависимости от условия

Tags: java, javafx

Желательно только ячейку, но если проще выделить всю строку, то можно итак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разукрасить строку целиком, вам необходимо проставить свою `RowFactory`

```
tableView.setRowFactory((param) -> new ColorRow());
```

где

```
private class ColorRow extends TableRow < myClass > {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(myClass vars, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(myClass, b);
        boolean flag = true; // тут условие, по которому стоит разукрашитьвать строку или нет.
        if (flag) {
            this.getStyleClass().add('redRow');
        } else {
            this.getStyleClass().add('greenRow');
        }
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы разукрасить какую-либо конкретную ячейку, необходимо переопредлить `CellFactory`

```
tableView.setCellFactory(param -> new ColorCell());
```

где

```
private class ColorCell extends TableCell < MyClass, String > {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyClass myClass, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(myClass, b);
        boolean flag = true; // тут условие, по которому стоит разукрашитьвать ячейку или нет.
        if (flag) {
            this.getStyleClass().add('redCell');
        } else {
            this.getStyleClass().add('greenCell');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не могу оптимизировать под свой код, компилятор ругается.
на что заменить "myClass"?

Comment: На то, чем параметризована ваша таблица